# How to add skype for phonecall for lead in crm 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-4, dynamics-crm-online

im new to crm 2011 ,I need to call the particular lead. is there possibility to add skype to phone call in crm 2011 in lead page.which means is there any solutions are available to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you search in google you will find more options but i give you some tips. After UR12 you can call via skype you can see [here](http://blog.sonomapartners.com/2013/01/microsoft-dynamics-crm-polaris-and-ur12-update.html) all features of this rollup. If you have a latter version you have two options a [workaround](http://www.magnetismsolutions.co.nz/blog/11-07-14/Double_Click_to_Call_Skype_in_Dynamics_CRM_2011.aspx) or via [connector](http://everythingcrm.net/2012/02/06/releasing-skype-connector-for-dynamics-crm-2011/).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question and your issue might had solved.

But I have worked on this requirement and written one Blog.
[Skype Status on CRM Form](http://mscrmmindfire.wordpress.com/2013/09/10/skype-status-on-crm-form/)

Please take a look.

The logic is to Populate the Skype Status Dynamically using one Anchor and Image tag.

```
<a href="skype:taditdash?chat">
    <img src="http://mystatus.skype.com/balloon/taditdash" 
         style="border: none;" width="150" height="60" 
         alt="My status" />
</a>
```

Here `taditdash` is my *Skype Id*.

Anchor `href` `"skype:taditdash?chat"` will prompt Skype for Chatting.
If you want to call, then you need to pass `"skype:taditdash?call"`.

So, one `WebResource` is created and this `HTML` is generated dynamically to reflect the *Skype Status*.

Comment: @kleopatra Most Welcome. :) And thanks for directing me in the right path.